# ASP.NET MVC Razor - JavaScript execution aborts when C# variables are emitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I upgraded an MVC3 proj to MVC4 and it appears some javascript functions are not being called after I emit some C# in Razor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var obj = @(Html.Raw(Model.InterestsJson)) ;

    alert('This is never called.');
}); 
</script>
```

When I extract the emitted string from my Model.interestsJson, javascript functions run normally.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var obj = [{ "Id": 1, "Name": "Sports" }, { "Id": 2, "Name": "Entertainment" }];
    alert('This will now be called'); 
}); 
</script>
```

What is weird is that this did work up until I upgraded the project to MVC4.

The first thing I did was check for js errors but nothing threw an exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just love the `it does not work` problem description. It's so exhaustive. It provides so much details. It's a love. Please go ahead and read http://sscce.org and ask a real question because I can put the snippet you have shown in a jsfiddle and prove you that it works. The conclusion is that there is something else in your code that you didn't show that's causing the problem. And by mentioning a problem, what is it? Error message? Something? Did you check the FireBug console? Was there something?

Answer (score 1):

The `@(Html.Raw(Model.InterestsJson))` statement emits invalid JS code, so next statement cannot be parsed. Open page source and check what's wrong with it.

Probably, this should fix the problem.

```
@{ Html.Raw(Model.InterestsJson); }
```